# Does anyone have a Simulink library model to publish to ROS

Tags: ros, publish

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I was wondering if anyone knows how to publish to ROS from Simulink?  I'd like to simply drop down a library block with a mask and then enter the publisher in the mask.  The data can be run in an Inport and the publisher can be declared in an external C file.  Any ideas?

Thanks,

Jason

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61624/does-anyone-have-a-simulink-library-model-to-publish-to-ros/) by [JasonB007](https://answers.ros.org/users/4771/jasonb007/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-04-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have no direct experience with any Simulink <-> ROS bridges, but there are several options that might work for your use case:

- Simulink <-> OROCOS: using the [orocos-simulink-toolbox](http://www.orocos.org/orocos/orocos-simulink-toolbox). OROCOS then has a ROS transport
- ROS <-> Matlab: several implementations exist, see the [groovy/Planning/Matlab](http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Planning/Matlab) page for an overview. From there you might be able to create an S-function block (although according to [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/12542/rosmatlab-simulink-communication) answer, that could be hard / impossible)
- [ros_simulink](https://github.com/abubeck/ros_simulink): this one doesn't seem to be included on the Groovy planning page. Seems a bit stale (last commit: 3 years ago)
- write your own (MEX and / or S-function) using the appropriate roscpp libraries (again, see [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/12542/rosmatlab-simulink-communication) answer for some details)

---

Originally posted by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) with karma: 1416 on 2013-04-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1